# Is there any ASP.NET web control specialized in displaying video?

Tags: asp.net, web-control

Is there any ASP.NET web control specialized in displaying video?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Visit the following link:

http://www.aspnet-video.com/

Or you can consider using Silverlight:

http://www.silverlight.net/

Comment: I've installed asp-video apparently with success. But, I can't find its icon any where in the toolbox

Comment: I've restarted Visual Studio, but I'm not seeing the icon. Maybe the questions need to be (i) "What type of icon am I supposed to expect" and (ii) under which category? [Standard, ...]"

Comment: According to the website, I'm supposed to get the icons under the "AspNet" tab. I'll try to install it manually

Comment: I've noticed that, when I installed the product, I was asked to choose the appropriate VS Toolbox. The choices were 2003, 2005, and 2008. But, I am using VS2010 professional edition. Maybe that's the reason the icons are not showing up

Answer (score 1):

Media players are very easy to set up in Silverlight, which embeds easily into ASP.NET. Silverlight provides an ASP.NET control as one option for embedding.

Comment: Can Media players display Flash or Real Player?